# trying to generate automated login java code

Tags: webclient, htmlunit, java

I have been trying to build a java program to perform automatic login to a web page but i am using the code below

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.applet.*;
class main {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

   final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

   // Fake page
   final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://example/login.php");

  // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
 // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
   final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("login_form");

   final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("Submit");
   final HtmlTextInput username = form.getInputByName("username");
   final HtmlTextInput psswd = form.getInputByName("password");

// Fake username and password
   username.setValueAttribute("username");
   psswd.setValueAttribute("password");

// Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
   final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
  }
}
```

but i had been getting the error WebClient not found, HTMLUnit not found.
Iam not using eclipse or any other kind similar to it. I am using Sublime text3 for writting the java code. Provide me with the correct import package to remove the errors. I had search the internet for this and had already downloaded HTMLUNIt packages from internet and put them in my enivronment path variable.

Comment: _Provide me with the correct import package to remove the errors_ We are not _eclipse or any other kind similar to it_

Comment: Show us how you compile your code. Are you using Maven, Gradle or just a javac command?

Comment: i am using javac command to compile it

Comment: @Deepak Sharma: how does the classpath passed as a parameter look like? Did you add the HtmlJunit jar to the classpath?

Comment: You need to import the HtmlUnit packes...(i.e. import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient)